# Simple npm site displays This site can’t be reached

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu

My simple website can't be reached suddenly!!  It's hosted in AWS EC2 (free tier) using Ubuntu.  The site is running using "npm start" in the root of the website.  The site displays "This site can’t be reached".  I have security group setup for the port for both 0.0.0.0/0 and ::/0.  If I log onto the EC2 box and curl the public DNS IP address I get the html I expect but not remotely in my browser!?

Does anyone know what commands I can run either on the EC2 box or locally to trace whether my request is getting into the EC2 or what else is going wrong suddenly?  I've tried the following

```
$ lsof -t -i :3000 (no process found)
$ npm start 
$ lsof -t -i :3000 (process found ~ 6205)
$ curl ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000
```

My root folder file structure looks like the following

- README.md
- awscli-bundle
- build.sh
- package-lock.json
- public
- build
- node_modules
- package.json
- src

Many thanks,

**Update (after running wget on the EC2)**

```
wget ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000
--2019-03-20 23:42:04--  http://ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000/
Resolving ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com)... ec2-1-2-3-4
Connecting to ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com (ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com)|ec2-1-2-3-4|:3000... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 2245 (2.2K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html                            100%[=======================================================================>]   2.19K  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2019-03-20 23:42:04 (343 MB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [2245/2245]
```

Comment: try doing a `wget ec2-1-2-3-4.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000` and see what is returned.

Comment: Just provided an updated after trying that on the EC2, will do that remotely now

Comment: Can you give us the uncensored URL?

Comment: Okay, but if it's okay maybe I'll delete this comment later ec2-34-244-118-186.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000

Comment: My machine is a mac, the wget command isn't recognised.

Comment: Works fine here. You're not accidentally going to `ec2-34-244-118-186.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` without the port in the browser, are you?

Comment: @James Use `curl -I` instead if you don't have `wget`.

Comment: It doesn't work for me! :-( . Is there something I can do?

Comment: What does `curl -I ec2-34-244-118-186.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:3000` output for you? (From your local Mac.)

Comment: the curl command is just hanging at the moment

Comment: curl: (7) Failed to connect to ec2-34-244-118-186.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 3000: Operation timed out

Comment: What do you get if you `dig ec2-34-244-118-186.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`? Is it possible you're behind a corporate firewall that's blocking 3000?

Comment: I just stopped my work VPN to see and it works now?!!!  If that's the reason why would that make a difference?  Sorry for being stupid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just stopped my work VPN to see and it works now?

It's fairly common for work networks to block unusual ports. That appears to be your issue here.